# Retrieving text from specific class HTML tags and storing into an array in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, discord.py, read-eval-print-loop

I'm in the process of creating a Discord bot and I'm starting at the bottom.  The first piece that I'm trying to tackle is using BeautifulSoup.  My current code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
pbe_titles = soup.find_all('h1', attrs={'class': 'news-title'})
for tag in pbe_titles :
  print(tag.text.strip())
```

So far, this does exactly what I need it to do.
It retrieves all the text between the  tags identified by class "news-title" i.e.
`<h1 class="news-title">text here</h1>` and prints out all the text of all tags associated by that class.  Now, I want to take all those titles that BeautifulSoup found and store them into an array that I can print out into my discord client.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
pbe_titles = soup.find_all('h1', attrs={'class': 'news-title'})
for tag in pbe_titles :
  totalTags = [tag.text.strip()]


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$show'):
        await message.channel.send(totalTags)

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

The problem I'm running into here is that the `totalTags = [tag.text.strip()]` only returns one of the titles, not all.  But if I just stick to `print(tag.text.strip())` it will print the 15+ titles.  What am I doing incorrectly regarding my array?

Comment: `totalTags = [tag.text.strip() for tag in pbe_titles]` ?

Comment: Your current code would ovewrite rather than append

Comment: I have a follow-up question after having that portion solved.   If I wanted to use BeautifulSoup to find other tags within the tag I'm already in, how would I do that?  For example-- in each title, theres an embedded a href link as its a link to another website-- Is there a way to create a two dimensional array that stores that link associated with each title?

Comment: generate tuples within list comprehension then convert to dataframe for example. The iterator would be a parent element of both target elements or the target if a match with a child/sibling as the other match.

Answer (score 1):

So in python, you want to have a list of those. You can factor that out into a generator function and turn that into a list like so:

```py
def get_titles(soup):
    pbe_titles = soup.find_all('h1', attrs={'class': 'news-title'})
    for tag in pbe_titles :
        yield tag.text.strip()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
titles = list(get_titles(soup))
print(titles)
```

or you can just use list comprehension

```py
titles = [tag.text.strip() 
          for tag in soup.find_all('h1', attrs={'class': 'news-title'})]
```

Comment: I have two questions but thank you, that is starting to get where I needed it to be
1: So the output is just a paragraph block rather than separating each title individually-- is there a way to change that so each title is its own element in the array?
2: When I print, it leaves opening and closing brackets at the beginning and end of the paragraph block of titles respectively.  Is there a way to get rid of those?

Comment: The code above should give you precisely that, a list of strings (titles). You can provide more context on what you're trying to achieve and I can perhaps answer more.

Comment: `final_titles = '\n'.join(titles)` I was actually able to do it this way-- I just didn't want a block of text with no "new lines" between each title